# What is hTAP?? Please help

Tags: biochemistry, cell-biology, bioinformatics, immunology

Could not find a single article regarding this. What is hTAP? Tap is Transfer associated protein, that I know, but what is hTAP??
(I have not studied biology since last 8 years and now I am going through it because I need it for my research. So if someone can describe it in simple language it would be very helpful)

Comment: From which context do you have this?

Comment: I recommend that you put some more effort into your questions, they're mostly lacking context and are often rather easy to google.

Comment: I did search for hTAP, did not find any useful information

Comment: You definitely need to add some context - what sentence(s) did you see it in, and where? A Web Of Science search for hTAP in the TITLE field points to "Human thyrotropin-releasing hormone-associated peptide" but that doesn't appear to be relevant. It isn't unusual for acronyms like this to have several meanings.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question lacks any effort whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hTAP refers to human TAP protein ([reference](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10454577)). And how do you know that TAP refers to Transfer Associated Protein? I believe it stands for Transporter Associated with Antigen Processing ([reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transporter_associated_with_antigen_processing)). Your facts are wrong which is why your question couldn't be answered.

Comment: http://www.springer.com/biomed/immunology/book/978-1-4939-1114-1
this book has TAp written as transfer associated protein

Comment: @user3237995 I don't know about the book because I don't have it but that article definitely mentions TAP as Transporter Associated with Antigen Processing in the abbreviation section. So why did you link me to it?